# Checkbox is not getting displayed in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox, dropdown

I have to do the multi select from the dropdown. So I have referred this [link](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/multiselect/?). But when I try to open this program in the browser I dont see tthe checkbox and I cant select more data also.
My script looks like this

```
<html>
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--Stylesheets-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--JS-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        </head>

<body>
        <select multiple>
                <option value="a">a</option>
                <option value="b">b</option>
                <option value="c">c</option>
              </select>
        <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <select
          class="select" multiple
          id="basic-select"
          data-mdb-validation="true"
          data-mdb-valid-feedback="This value is valid"
          data-mdb-invalid-feedback="This value is invalid"
          data-mdb-clear-button="true">
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
          <option value="3">Three</option>
          <option value="4">Four</option>
          <option value="5">Five</option>
          <option value="6">Six</option>
          <option value="7">Seven</option>
          <option value="8">Eight</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-3">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
<script>
        (() => {
  'use strict';

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation');

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach((form) => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();

      form.classList.add('was-validated');
    },false);
  });
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My chrome version is 90.0.
Here I tried with two examples. I can see two dropdowns are showing without checkbox.Can someone help me how should i show the checkbox and do the multiple selection

Comment: Are you using the PRO version? Since that is necessary according to the [docs](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/multiselect/): *"Note: This component requires MDBootstrap Pro package."*

Comment: If you want to have the dropdown in the multiple select like the mdb shown, you need to include the library of the mdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Display Checkboxes In Dropdown

**Add HTML:**

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">

    <title>SELECT</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="select222.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <h4>checkbox</h4>
            <select class="js-select2" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="O1" data-badge="">Option1</option>
                <option value="O2" data-badge="">Option2</option>
                <option value="O3" data-badge="">Option3</option>
                <option value="O4" data-badge="">Option4</option>
                <option value="O5" data-badge="">Option5</option>
                <option value="O6" data-badge="">Option6</option>
                <option value="O7" data-badge="">Option7</option>
                <option value="O8" data-badge="">Option8</option>
                <option value="O9" data-badge="">Option9</option>
                <option value="O10" data-badge="">Option10</option>
                <option value="O11" data-badge="">Option11</option>
                <option value="O12" data-badge="">Option12</option>
                <option value="O13" data-badge="">Option13</option>
            </select>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**Add CSS:**

```css
body { 
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.select2-container {
  min-width: 400px;
}

.select2-results__option {
  padding-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.select2-results__option:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #e9e9e9;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]:before {
  font-family:fontAwesome;
  content: "\f00c";
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f77750;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected] {
    background-color: #eaeaeb;
    color: #272727;
}
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--multiple {
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple {
    border-color: #f77750;
    border-width: 2px;
}
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple {
    border-width: 2px;
}
.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown--below {
    
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

}
.select2-selection .select2-selection--multiple:after {
    content: 'hhghgh';
}
/* select with icons badges single*/
.select-icon .select2-selection__placeholder .badge {
    display: none;
}
.select-icon .placeholder {
    display: none;
}
.select-icon .select2-results__option:before,
.select-icon .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]:before {
    display: none !important;
    /* content: "" !important; */
}
.select-icon  .select2-search--dropdown {
    display: none;
}
```

**Add JQuery:**

```js
        $(".js-select2").select2({
            closeOnSelect : false,
            placeholder : "Placeholder",
            allowHtml: true,
            allowClear: true,
            tags: true // создает новые опции на лету
        });

            $('.icons_select2').select2({
                width: "100%",
                templateSelection: iformat,
                templateResult: iformat,
                allowHtml: true,
                placeholder: "Placeholder",
                dropdownParent: $( '.select-icon' ),//обавили класс
                allowClear: true,
                multiple: false
            });
    

                function iformat(icon, badge,) {
                    var originalOption = icon.element;
                    var originalOptionBadge = $(originalOption).data('badge');
                 
                    return $('<span><i class="fa ' + $(originalOption).data('icon') + '"></i> ' + icon.text + '<span class="badge">' + originalOptionBadge + '</span></span>');
                }
```

Works Like Charm

Comment: Hi I tried your script. I can see only Option 1,2,3,4. I am not able to select anything and I dont see any checkbox also

Comment: i just updated the script, this works as per your requirements.

Comment: Want to play with code check here:  https://codepen.io/faur/pen/vWVPGE