# Adding autocomplete for multiselct using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have added the questions [Checkbox is not getting displayed in dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67487265/checkbox-is-not-getting-displayed-in-dropdown) here for adding mulitselect dropdown.
Here I used mbootstarp but I dont want to get the package here. So I tried adding multiselect dropdown
by following this link https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-jQuery-UI-Plugin-For-Simle-Tokenized-Autocomplete-Autocomplete-Multiselect.html#google_vignette.

```
<html>
     <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"/>

    <!--JS-->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://jquery.autocomplete.multiselect.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="myautocomplete" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myautocomplete").click(function(){
        /* Local Data */
        var carList = [
                "Audi S6", "Audi S6", "Austin-Healey", "Alfa Romeo", "Aston Martin",
                "BMW 7 ", "Bentley Mulsanne", "Bugatti Veyron",
                "Chevrolet Camaro", "Cadillac ",
                "Duesenberg J ", "Dodge Sprinter",
                "Elantra", "Excavator",
                "Ford Boss 302", "Ferrari 360", "Ford Thunderbird ",
                "GAZ Siber"];

        $('#myautocomplete').autocomplete({ source: carList, width: 205, multiselect:true});
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After adding this code I can see the dropdown and I can add only one data. I cant add more than one data and I dont see the proprely selected also. Can some one help me in this?

Comment: You can't include multiple versions of jQuery and jQuery UI on the same page

Comment: If you have removed incorrect links to jQuery library, please Edit your post and update the Code to reflect the current scripts.

Comment: I edited it can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How To Multiselect & Autocomplete Using Jquery.

**First Add Javascript:**

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="src/jquery.autocomplete.multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

**Add HTML:**

```html
<input id="myAutocomplete" type="text" />
```

**Jquery:**

```js
$(function(){
var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
];
$('#myAutocomplete').autocomplete({
source: availableTags,
multiselect: true
});
})
```

Hope you find helpful.

Comment: Note: i have used my parameters(programming lanuanges), someone can use according to their needs.